# Function displaying wrong background images when hovering DIVS in reverse

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I am using jQuery to change a background image of a DIV when you hover over 1 of 6 columns (the image changes every time you hover on each of the columns) for the most post I got this to work:

```
$('.content1').hover(function() {
    $('.services-hover').animate({opacity: 0}, 0).css({'background-image': "url(http://aliensix.com/services-websites.jpg)"}).animate({opacity: 1}, 500)
}, function() {
    $('.services-hover').animate({opacity: 0}, 0).css({'background-image': "url(http://aliensix.com/services-apps.jpg)"}).animate({opacity: 1}, 500)
});

$('.content2').hover(function() {
    $('.services-hover').animate({opacity: 0}, 0).css({'background-image': "url(http://aliensix.com/services-photos.jpg)"}).animate({opacity: 1}, 500)
}, function() {
    $('.services-hover').animate({opacity: 0}, 0).css({'background-image': "url(http://aliensix.com/services-icons.jpg)"}).animate({opacity: 1}, 500)
});

$('.content3').hover(function() {
    $('.services-hover').animate({opacity: 0}, 0).css({'background-image': "url(http://aliensix.com/services-support.jpg)"}).animate({opacity: 1}, 500)
}, function() {
    $('.services-hover').animate({opacity: 0}, 0).css({'background-image': "url(http://aliensix.com/services-audio.jpg)"}).animate({opacity: 1}, 500)
});
```

But I have 2 issues, first when you first hover over each div the background flashes before the image appears, this only happens on the first time you hover.

My biggest problem is if you go through each div backwards and hover over it, the wrong image is displayed and I believe this only happens on "apps" and "icons". Do I need to have 6 handlers instead of 3?

I have set up a fiddle displaying this problem: https://jsfiddle.net/hqa8k0ze/6/

Is there a "cleaner" way I can do this, without the issues?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g029boot/1/ - the apps/icon elements does not have any `content<d>` class so hovering over it doesn't do anything

Comment: this is just a tip and not the solution to your problem but your design is annoying and rather inaccessible, you should think a little more in the UI / UX before trying to solve your problem

Comment: Do you want to show the same image for both `website` and `apps`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g029boot/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny what do you mean, hovering over anything inside .services-content will trigger the script? Xzegga, which part of it? And Arun, all images are different.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g029boot/3/ ? - there are 6 `services-content` elements but only 3 hover handlers?

Comment: @ArunPJohny I am still having the same issue, if you switch between apps & photos the wrong photo is shown for apps, it should be the hand with the phone instead of the desk with laptop on it.

Comment: @ve1jdramas sorry... not sure I'm getting you...

Comment: @ArunPJohny yes, I only have 3 right now should there be six? But the issue is the wrong images are being displayed when you hover over each div like apps or icons for example, and now when you take your mouse off of the hover another image fades in.

Comment: It looks to me like the images are only loading when the script is called for each image. I have confirmed that with Chrome Dev Tools. However, that may only be on the example because you're loading in images from an external domain. When I remove the `.animate({opacity: 0}, 0)` it no longer flashes the black background but I suspect that what you're trying to do needs 2 containers. An extra one to put the new image into underneath the old image and then fade into it. By the way it's hard to understand exactly what you want so maybe a little more explanation will help.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just set the default background in CSS body element and then have each div show it's own image whenever the mouse enters the column. Essentially just covering the default background with a new background instead of making the default opacity 0.
It's likely flashing because you are changing the opacity of the background to 0 before bringing in the new image.